# ReactJS- Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Hi i am writing a basic messaging app with react and firebase everything is working except for passing in the firebase data as props to display on the screen. Right now I am getting this error:`react-dom.development.js:11340 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, message, timestamp, user}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead`
Here is the code for my App.js:

```
import "./App.css";
import { FormControl, InputLabel, Input, Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import SendIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Send";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { db } from "./firebase";
// import firebase from "firebase";
import Message from "./Message";
import firebase from "@firebase/app";

function App() {
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState("");
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  console.log(messages);
  console.log(db);

  const getMessages = () => {
    db.collection("messages").onSnapshot(function (querySnapshot) {
      setMessages(
        querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          message: doc.data().message,
          timestamp: doc.data().timestamp,
          user: doc.data().user,
        }))
      );
    });
  };
  console.log(messages);

  const sendMessage = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    db.collection("messages").add({
      message: input,
      timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      user: userName,
    });

    setInput("");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setUserName(prompt("Enter Your Name"));
    getMessages();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Welcome {userName}!</h1>
      <div className="form-div">
        <form className="form">
          <FormControl className="form-input">
            <InputLabel>Enter a Message</InputLabel>
            <Input
              value={input}
              onChange={(e) => {
                setInput(e.target.value);
              }}
            />
          </FormControl>
          <div className="button-div">
            <Button
              style={{ backgroundColor: "rgb(0, 110, 255)" }}
              className="send-button"
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              type="submit"
              onClick={sendMessage}
              disabled={!input}
            >
              <SendIcon></SendIcon>
            </Button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>

      {messages.map((message, id) => (
        <>
          <Message key={id} message={message}></Message>
        </>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and here is the code for my Message component:
import React from "react";

```
const Message = (message) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{message.message}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Message;.
```

Help would be much appreciated as i am beginner i have tried other soultions like downgrading firebase but i still get this error. i have also tried passing the props as individuls e.g message=message.message but i still get same error

Comment: What is the output of your `console.log(messages)` ?

Comment: Seems `message.message` is holding an object, please check what is in it?

Comment: @Ravikumar it is an array with objects inside App.js:14 (13) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

Comment: As said by @Ravikumar your `message.message` seems to be an object so you have to extract only the `string` you want to display

Answer (score 0):

There is confusion in your code as you are using `message` keyword everywhere, I would suggest you to use proper variable names.

Seems your messages structure looks like

`[{id: 1, message: 'hi', user: 'asd', timestamp: ''}, {id: 2, message: 'hi1', user: 'asd1', timestamp: ''}]`

Just change your `Message` component like below

```
const Message = ({message: msgInst}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{msgInst.message}</p>
      <p>{msgInst.user}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Dude thank you So so much!!!!! I have been stuck on this for ages and you fix this bug for me Thank you!